# vector std::out_of_range in my own template class(vector of pointers to list Nodes), but I can't see why

Tags: c++, list, vector

I am writing codes for a template class with linked list and vectors of pointers to some nodes in the linked list. The code is ugly because I just wrote what I thought might work, and corrected it focusing on fixing the error messages.

The list (accordingly, the vector, too) is kept sorted because it finds the right position with position method every time it insert an item.

Initially, I had a lot of errors, and I was able to fix them after a lot of trying.
Now it compiles, but when I tested it with a main method if this template class works fine, it throws an error message:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

what():  vector::_M_range_check

Aborted (core dumped)

I know what std::out_of_range is, but I really do not see why this error occurs.
There is not even many parts in my code that accesses elements of the vector.

The following is the code for the testing main method, and the next is the definition for my template class(and the nested iterator class).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ValliHN.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Valli<string> valli;

    valli.insert("K");
valli.insert("H");
valli.insert("N");
valli.insert("H");
valli.insert("J");

for (Valli<string>::iterator i = valli.begin(); i != valli.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The template class

```
#include"DList.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::vector;

template<typename I>
class Valli {

vector< DNode<I>* > va;
DList<I> lli;
size_t ratio;
friend class iterator;
friend class DList<I>;

public: 

class iterator {

  typename DList<I>::iterator list_iter;
  iterator(DNode<I>* node) 
   : list_iter(typename DList<I>::iterator(node)) { }
  friend class Valli<I>;
  friend class DList<I>;

public:
     I& operator*() const {
        return *list_iter;
     }

     iterator& operator++() {
        ++list_iter;
        return *this;
     }

     iterator operator++(int) {
        iterator* ret = this;
        ++list_iter;
        return *ret;
     }

     iterator& operator--() {
        --list_iter;
        return *this;
     }

     iterator operator--(int) {
        typename DList<I>::iterator ret = list_iter;
        --list_iter;
        return ret;
     }

     bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const {
        return list_iter == rhs.list_iter;
     }

     bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const {
        return list_iter != rhs.list_iter;
     }

     DNode<I>* returnCurr() const {
        return list_iter.returnCurr();
     }
};

explicit Valli<I>(size_t ratio=4)
 : ratio(ratio),
  lli(DList<I>()),
  va(vector< DNode<I>* >()) { }

//   Valli<I>()
//    : Valli<I>(4) { }

~Valli<I>() {
//      delete[] va;
//      delete lli;
}

iterator insert(const I& item) {
   iterator pos = position(va, item);
   lli.insert(pos.returnCurr(), item);
   refresh(4);
   return --pos;
}

iterator find(const I& item) const {
  iterator start = iterator(va.at(binsearch(va, item)));
  iterator end = iterator(va.at(binsearch(va, item)+1));
  while(start != end) {
     if(*start = item) {
        return start;
     }
     else {
        ++start;
     }
  }
}
//   void erase(iterator itr) {}

iterator begin() const {
   lli.begin();
}

iterator end() const {
   lli.end();
}

private:
int binsearch(const vector< DNode<I>* > vec, const I& item) const {
  int left = 0;
  int right = vec.size()-1;
  while(left <= right) {
     int mid = (left+right)/2;
     iterator iter = iterator(vec.at(mid));
     if(item < *iter) {
        right = mid-1;
     }
     else if(item == *iter) {
        return mid;
     }
     else {
        left = mid+1;
     }
  }
  return left;
 }

iterator position(const vector< DNode<I>* > vec, const I& item) const {
  iterator start = iterator(vec.at(binsearch(vec, item)));
  iterator end = iterator(vec.at(binsearch(vec, item)+1));
  while(start != end) {
     if(*start < item) {
        ++start;
     }
     else {
        return start;
     }
  }

}

void refresh(size_t newRatio) {
  iterator iter = begin();
  int count = 0;
  va.clear();
  while(iter!=end()) {
     if(count % newRatio == 0) {
        va.push_back(iter.returnCurr());
     }
     //push_backing the last node - to be added
     iter++;
     count++;
  }
}

};
```

The class DList.h is very similar to the standard library list class.
Can you see the problem in my code?
Also, could you tell me if my code overall looks good or bad, in terms of both good programming practices and the implementation of the coding direction?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Look to me like you have a vector out of range on the first insert. insert calls position, which calls binsearch. binsearch returns 0 because the vector is empty, position then calls vector.at(0) (and vector.at(1)). Both of those are out of range errors because the vector is empty.

I'm just staring at the code so I might have made a mistake. Really you should use a debugger, and find out exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: Seems right, but when I tried to correct it, it did not work. Can you tell me exactly what I should do? Thanks

Comment: @user25409 That's hard because I'm not following your code in enough detail to understand the purpose. All I can suggest is that you document each function, what exactly is it supposed to return, especially in the edge cases like empty vectors. Doing that might give you a clearer idea of where the mistakes are.